# Connect Web application to an offline compiler (Java/Python)

Tags: java, python, node.js, angular, compiler-services

I am creating an application where the student enters the code in the front- end(Angular).The code will be sent to back-end(NODE) for compilation and run. I know about HACKER-EARTH API which can be used to get the compilation and output results through API calls. I want to make this application available offline (INTRANET not INTERNET).Is there any possible way so that my application can communicate with the compilers (JAVA,PYTHON,C) installed on the system to compile the given code and return the results?

Any resources/Links would be very helpful.

Please help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First write a file of the code you get from the front end then(if the file is written successfully) you can use spawn or exec from child processes to call the compilers and executing the code and get the stdout and stderr.
You can refer to https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html for child processes

You can also use these packages or refer to their code

https://www.npmjs.com/package/compile-run

https://www.npmjs.com/package/compilex